# Encode é to &eacute; but not &"233;

Tags: c#

I'm finding a way to encode a string.

Eg

Input:

```
é
```

I want

Output:

```
&eacute;
```

I use

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("éàè");
```

But it give me

```
&#233;
```

Comment: `&#233;` is a perfectly valid way to encode é for HTML.  If you don't like it, you can always use `String.Replace()` to replace `&#233;` with `&eacute;`.

Comment: What about System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode ?

Comment: Already use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode but give me &#233;

Comment: What is full syntax for String.Replace() and which library

Comment: @Aroniaina, read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: hope you need to have a mapping dictionary to replace &#233 with &eacute